How pinescript V5 applies external data
I want to use Pinescript to quote BTC's contract positions, but unfortunately tradingview does not have this data. I can only consider quoting from outside. How should I use Pinescript to drink it?
I checked that the requests function is not supported, and I also checked seeds and have stopped updating at present.

AFAIK it´s currently not possible to include external data in Tradingview or pine-script. request.seed() looked promising, but they don´t accept new repos. Thus I use Python and matplotlib plots to visualize external data
